# What contour to use the residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Calculate
$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{-\infty }
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{2n}+1},\,\,\, n\in \mathbb{N}$ with
$n\in \mathbb{N}^{*}$.

I'm a bit thrown off by the bounds of this integral, in class we always used the upper half circle but does this mean I should use the lower half?
In which case $-i$ is the residue I'm considering?

Thank you,
-Velyth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, surely you can notice that
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^{2n}+1}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{1}{x^{2n}+1}dx=-\int_0^{-\infty} \frac{1}{x^{2n}+1}dx
$$
because $\frac{1}{x^{2n}+1}$ is an even function. Now we focus on finding
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{x^{2n}+1} dx=2\pi i \sum_k Res(\frac{1}{x^{2n}+1},x_k),
$$
where $x_k$ are zeros of ${x^{2n}+1}$ on the upper half plane. All $x_k$ are distinct and not repeated. We can actually write $x_k=e^{\frac{2k-1}{2n}\pi i},k=1,\ldots,n.$

Then you can go on to calculate the residues.
$$
Res(\frac{1}{x^{2n}+1},e^{\frac{2k-1}{2n}\pi i})=\lim_{z\to e^{\frac{2k-1}{2n}\pi i}} \frac{z-e^{\frac{2k-1}{2n}\pi i}}{z^{2n}+1}\\
=\lim_{z\to e^{\frac{2k-1}{2n}\pi i}} \frac{1}{2nz^{2n-1}}\\
=\frac{1}{2ne^{\frac{(2k-1)(2n-1)}{2n}\pi i}}
$$
Where we have used L'Hopital's rule in the second equality. Further,
$$
Res(\frac{1}{x^{2n}+1},e^{\frac{2k-1}{2n}\pi i})={(2n)^{-1}e^{-\frac{(2k-1)(2n-1)}{2n}\pi i}}\\
={(2n)^{-1}ne^{-\frac{(2k-1)}{2}(2-1/n)\pi i}}={-(2n)^{-1}e^{-\frac{(2k-1)}{2}(-1/n)\pi i}}\\
=-\frac{1}{2n}e^{\frac{2k-1}{2n}\pi i}
$$
Now can you continue?

Take the sum:
$$
2\pi i \sum_{k=1}^{n}  (-\frac{1}{2n})e^{\frac{2k-1}{2n}\pi i}\\
=2\pi i (-\frac{1}{2n}) \frac{1-(e^{\pi i/n})^{n}}{1-e^{\pi i/n}}e^{\frac{\pi i}{2n}}\\
=-\frac{\pi}{n} \frac{2i}{1-e^{\pi i/n}}e^{\frac{\pi i}{2n}}\\
=-\frac{\pi}{n} \frac{2i}{e^{-\frac{\pi i}{2n}}-e^{\frac{\pi i}{2n}}}\\
=\frac{\pi}{n \sin\frac{\pi}{2n}}.
$$

You are done now.

Comment: @Velyth Why? the residue should not be zero. Please check your calculation. I will calculate residue later.

Comment: @Velyth The denominator also tends to zero!

Comment: The power we raise to is NOT a real number. Think twice.

Comment: I think I got it, rewriting $e^{i\pi \left(2k-1\right)}=e^{2k\cdot i\pi }e^{-i\pi }=-e^{2k\cdot \:i\pi \:}$
And since k=1,....,n $e$ always equals $1$, then $-1$, so indeed the denominator tends to $0$. 
What is the limit though?

Comment: @Velyth Use L'Hospita

Comment: Your limits seem to be still incorrect. Let me write the next move in a minute

Comment: @Velyth Look at my new answer

Comment: It's much easier if the chosen contour is a wedge that encloses only the pole at $e^{i\pi/2n}$

Comment: No, that is not the correct answer.  The integrand is real valued and the integration is over the positive reals.  The answer must be a real number.

Comment: You need to think through the analysis.  There is one pole enclosed by the wedge.  But, the contour integral has two segments that contribute to the residue while the third vanishes as we increase the radius of the circular arc segment to infinity.

Comment: @Velyth Yes. Go and evaluate this GP

Comment: @MarkViola Oh yes, that's very clever to integrate the wedge. But it is easier to think of to sum the GP.

Comment: @Velyth I finished my answer, but you could try it yourself first.

Comment: @HoldingArthur I think it's must easier to evaluate the integral of interest using a wedge contour.  It is easier yet to forgo complex analysis and use the Beta and Gamma functions.

Comment: @HoldingArthur Ok I understand, this is the integral from -inf to +inf. So following your first lines I should halve it and add a negative sign to find the integral from 0 to -inf then it's over, correct?

Comment: @Velyth Correct.

Comment: @MarkViola Could you please show your method as well? It doesn't seem to work for me.